# Making matrix in assembler MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I want to calculate Ax=b (A:3x3, x: 3x1) matrix. But there are not enough registers to store values in MIPS. So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: There's no need to have the entire matrices in registers, so I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Use the memory to store values.